# Validation before inserting into Gridview

Tags: asp.net, validation, gridview

I am adding data in gridview but not using sql, and my question is i want to validate first if i already inserted the data in the gridview before inserting. searching every data in my gridview before inserting, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, set `asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"` to this method, so when you click on insert it will execute this method, you can do the check before inserting:

Sample code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)        
{
    string val= textBox1.Text();
    \\check if the value already exists in the datasource you are binding to gridivew <br/>
   if(! value exists)
    \\ do the insert
}
```

Comment: thank you... uhmm, if you may, a sample of the \\check if the value already exist\\... again, thank you in advance...

Comment: May I know the datasource you are using to bind to gridview?